# Why postgres forced sslmode=verify-full though it it not there in the connection string

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc

I have removed sslmode=verify-full from the connection string still on running service it taking sslmode=verify-full. I have made ssl=true but removed sslmode. Is it in the valid connection string or anything more to be done?

Here is my url :

```
url="jdbc:amazon:postgresql://${apollo.OCF.FTPayDatabase.dbHost}:${apollo.OCF.FTPayDatabase.dbSock}/${apollo.OCF.FTPayDatabase.dbname}?ssl=true;sslrootcert=/apollo/env/RhythmTomcatBase/certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem"
```

Comment: It is the [documented behaviour](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html): _"The simplest being ssl=true, passing this into the driver will cause the driver to validate both the SSL certificate and verify the hostname (same as verify-full)."_

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

to your JDBC URL. This is covered in [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html#nonvalidating).